# _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".entry#"

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been coding in python using tkinter and came across an exception from the tinter library.

Since I don't know exactly what the error means, it is hard for me to debug my program. I was wondering if someone could outline the error and suggest what may have caused it, so that I know what to look for when debugging my program. `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".entry#"` (The hash represents a number).

I have an image showing the navigation through my program that causes the error if it helps.

[image: An image displaying the navigation through a tinter program. The user enters a cost configuration screen indirectly from the main menu, before exiting it and returning to the main menu. The user then tries to return to the same screen, but the error gets raised upon trying to get to it.]

Basically, the program will only let me view a sub-menu in the "record" section once, each time I run it, when it should let me enter them as many times as I need to.

Comment: Usually that means you are trying to call a method on a widget that has been destroyed. Please provide us with a [mcve] that reproduces this problem. And please take the time to post actual code rather than screenshots. Screenshots aren't searchable, are hard to read, and impossible to copy/paste from if we want to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should include the error as text and not as unreadable image.

Based on the error message, you're trying to call `.get()` on an Entry that doesn't exist anymore. Maybe the parent window has been destroyed/closed and the entry is not there anymore. Or maybe it is just a context thing... hard to tell without the code.

If you can't figure out, please edit your question and add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then I will edit my answer with more specific information.